# The pipe in my shower is not secured in any way, I’m trying to find a way to make the shower neck pipe secure, without doing any sheet rock work

Tags: shower

The showers neck pipe was never secured to any studs or anything else, I have tried to find a way to make it secure and not letting it move in and out of the wall every time someone is taking a shower. I’ve used hard rock plaster to do it, but after about a month it starts to break up the plaster and starts to move around again. It just wanted to get it to be nice and stable and not move at all , but I also don’t want to have to make the hole bigger and end up having to do some sheet rock work. The hole in the wall is approximately 2 inches around, and I can’t find anything that will fit into it so I can get it fixed. Do you have any ideas for me to try? The pipes don’t have any leaks in them, but I just don’t like the movement of the pipes every time we use the shower.

Comment: Really sheetrock/drywall work not that hard.  Trying to hack something that will work without making the hole bigger, will probably take four or five times longer than to cut into the sheetrock, fix the pipe, and repair the sheetrock.  Moving pipes tend to loosen/break pipe connections inside walls, not good.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of Split Flanges.

[image: split flange]

The split makes the easy to slip over the pipe without disconnecting your shower head.

They come with mounting holes to screw them to the wall.

Go to store and look them up.

Find one that fits your situation.

If you need to cut a small pice of rubber band and put it around the pipe to keep it firmly in place.

Comment: Could be, but not clear the OP has enough clearance to bolt a split flange to the studs or back wall.  If he follows @crip659 comment, then of course this is a great way to go.